# "_pickle.UnpicklingError: the STRING opcode argument must be quoted" in py2 to py3 ndarray transmission

Tags: python, numpy, sockets, pickle, ros

I have a workstation running Python2 with a ROS environment which obtains a camera image from a robot and sends it over the network to a Python3 machine using the standard `socket` library. I can't seem to unpickle correctly the opencv ndarray image.

I am able to successfully transfer simple data as lists, but I encounter an error when trying to transfer an image.

On the Python2 system, I obtain my image in this way:

```py
img = CvBridge().imgmsg_to_cv2(img_data, desired_encoding='bgr8')     # Convert from ROS image to OpenCV image
```

Obtaining an ndarray.
I serialize it with:

```py
data = pickle.dumps(img, protocol=0)
```

And I send it.
Back on the Python3 machine, I try to unpickle it using:

```py
response = pickle.loads(data_in, encoding='latin1')     # To read a Python2 dump
```

At this point, I obtain the following error:

```py
_pickle.UnpicklingError: the STRING opcode argument must be quoted
```

The only other solutions that I have found address cases in which data had been transferred between Unix and Windows machines, which is not my case.

Comment: np.load has a couple of parameters that deal with pickle differences between py2 and 3

Comment: @hpaulj np.load works with files, but my dataflow is camera > serialization > transmission, I never save the images

Answer (score -1, accepted):

An update on this topic, for possible future reference to whoever will experience the same problem.

The problem was not caused, as I initially thought, by a misconversion between Py2 and Py3 pickled byte stream. It was caused, instead, by the incorrect transmission of the data: I was interrupting the connection before all the packages had arrived.
This is the block of code that solved my problem:

```py
data_in = b''
while True:
    block = self.socket.recv(4096)
    if block:
        data_in += block
```

Answer (score 1):

In vscode (on windows 10), you should open file that is showing this error and then change option CRLF to LF and then save the file then `UnpicklingError: the STRING opcode argument must be quoted error` will be disappeared.

[image][image]